# How to set layer to the final state of an unexpectedly ended animation

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation, caanimation

I use the following code to rotate an image:

```
    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * 1];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 1;    // this results in a speed of one full rotation per second
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 100;
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    [self.imageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKeyPath:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

When the animation ends normally, after 100 rotations, the end of animation matches the beginning of animation, so I don't have to worry about the presentationLayer matching the layer (which could result in a snap-back effect).

However, if I end this operation, using:

```
    [self.imageView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

which is possible when the user taps the stop button, I need to match the presentationLayer to the layer, otherwise I get snapback to the original state.

I have tried:

```
    id value = [((CALayer *)self.imageView.layer.presentationLayer) valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    [self.imageView.layer setValue:value forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

didn't work (doesn't seem to do anything), and:

```
    self.imageView.layer.transform = ((CALayer *)self.imageView.layer.presentationLayer).transform;
```

didn't work either (I get an odd twist around the 45° XY axis).

I'm not sure what else to try.  In the past, when I've had to do similar things, I just needed to match the presentationLayer's position, or size or …, but I've never had to match it's rotational position.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't the answer I am looking for, here is my current workaround.  I'm still hoping someone has a better way (and will share :-).

If I can't set the current layer to the same position as the presentationLayer, then I am going to stop the animation after letting it run the remainder of a single rotation, so it ends up at the same point as what the layer looks like:

```
- (void) runSpinAnimation:(BOOL) run;
{

    id value = [((CALayer *)self.imageView.layer.presentationLayer) valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    [self.imageView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

    if (run) {
        rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * 1];
        rotationAnimation.duration = 1;
        rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;
        rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

        [self.imageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
    }
    else {
        float radians = ((NSNumber *)value).floatValue;
        if (radians < 0)
            radians = M_PI + radians;
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = @(radians);
        rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 1.0 /* full rotation*/ * 1];
        rotationAnimation.duration = 0.25;
        rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
        rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

        [self.imageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

    }

}
```